# Performance challenge: Box operations (HackerRank) (C, Python)

Tags: python, c, performance, optimization

Recently I've been doing some challenges on HackerRank and came across this [one](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/box-operations/problem). First, I tried with Python, and then C. Both of my codes failed due to timeout restrictions.

It would be very helpful, if someone can tell me what can be improved in (one of) my codes (performance-wise).

Thank you.

Challenge description:
[image: Challenge description]

C code:

```
int minBox(int *box, int l, int r){
    int min=box[l];
    for(int i = l+1; i<=r; i++)
        if(box[i] < min)
            min = box[i];
    
    return min;
}

int sumBox(int *box, int l, int r){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i = l; i<=r; i++)
        sum += box[i];

    return sum;
}

void operateOnBox(int *op, int *box){
    switch(op[0]){
        case 3:
            printf("%d\n", minBox(box, op[1], op[2]));
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("%d\n", sumBox(box, op[1], op[2]));
            break;

        case 1:
            for(int i = op[1]; i <= op[2]; i++)
                box[i] += op[3];

            break;

        case 2:
            for(int i = op[1]; i <= op[2]; i++)
                box[i] = (int) floor(box[i]/((float)op[3]));

            break;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n, q, *box;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    box = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", box+i);

    for(int i = 0; i<q; i++){
        int op[4];
        scanf("%d %d %d", op, op+1, op+2);

        if(op[0] == 1 || op[0] == 2)
            scanf("%d", op+3);
        
        operateOnBox(op, box);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Python 3 code:

```
def operate(op, box):
    if op[0] == 3:
            print(min(box[op[1]:op[2]+1]))
    elif op[0] == 4:
            print(sum(box[op[1]:op[2]+1]))
    elif op[0] == 1:
            box[op[1]:op[2]+1] = map(lambda x: x+op[3], box[op[1]:op[2]+1])
    elif op[0] == 2:
            box[op[1]:op[2]+1] = map(lambda x: math.floor(x/op[3]), box[op[1]:op[2]+1])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    nq = input().split()

    n = int(nq[0])

    q = int(nq[1])

    box = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    for i in range(q):
        op = list(map(int, input().split()))
        operate(op, box)
```

Comment: That is what the challenge **is** - finding an efficient solution. Naive code will pass the tests cases. Good luck! If you can't solve it, move on to another one.

Comment: Please note that, you should post the problem description here, as links can be broken.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm doing those challenges basically to learn new concepts/strategies to do things, and not to gain HackerRank's points/badges. That's why I'm sticking to this challenge. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you considered [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) which is rather different from the usual challenge sites?

Comment: @ZBay Thanks, I've added a screenshot of the challenge.

Comment: I have not looked at the problem or code in detail here, but you might have a look for repeated calculations that you can save for re-use, or computing parts of an expression outside of a loop. The problem does ask you: "can you perform all the operations efficiently? "

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I've done some of the challenges there. But, I'm particulary curious on how I could optimize these codes.

Comment: Remember too, that, for example, `x / 3 < y` is more efficient as `x < 3 * y`. Divisions are usually expensive. And when the inputs are integers, more accurate.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah thanks, I was looking for this kind of helpful tips. I'll see if I can use threads in HackerRank and try to optimize it.

Comment: Also, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be more suitable for this question.

Comment: @WeatherVane is it ok if I duplicate this thread there?

Comment: If you ask it there, it might be better to delete this question. Sorry if I was a little snappy at first. But finally, do you *need* to use floating point?

Comment: @WeatherVane don't worry about it. Thanks, I'll move it there.

Comment: I just edited the prvevious comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, I'll try to change it to an if statement to see if it improves anything.

Comment: regarding; `box = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`   This is a MAJOR time waster AND the code fails to pass the returned pointer to `free()`.   Suggest using: `int box[n];`  which makes use of the Variable array size` feature of C.  Of course, this statement needs to be after the value of `n` is read

Comment: due to context switches, the use of threads will make the application take longer, especially since it is NOT I/O bound

Answer (score 1):

using `scanf()` and `printf()` is very slow.  Suggest the following two functions;

```
void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c<58)
    {
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll make use of it.

Comment: I tweaked the code to take negative number into consideration, but I have the same results. (same number of test cases passed). [The code](https://pastebin.com/20wwcKMA)